# Unable to find gaussian primes for 241

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am trying to find gaussian primes using the method outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers

Using the Julia programming language and I am able to find k for the following equality up to p = 233. Here k = 3, which results in the following gaussian primes: 8+13i & 13+8i

```
 mod(mod(BigInt(k)^((p - 1) / 2), p), p) == mod(-1, p)
```

However, I am unable to find $k$ for the next prime $p = 241?$

Comment: DId you try $\;15\pm4i\;$ ?

Comment: For efficiency, this is awful - it is better to have an exponent-mod function, which can compute $k^m\bmod p$ in $O(\log m\log p)$ time.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was the answer. I found a function in Julia call called powermod() that did the trick and it was interesting to learn about modular exponentiation.